# Using XPath Selector In Selenium to capture disabled check-box and sibling's href value

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium

I am using Selenium (with .NET/language is C#) with IE9 and have following html markup (relevant piece)

```
    <tr>
        <td class="a" align="b">
            <span class="i"/>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" name="chkBox" value="100" disabled/>
            </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/links/items/100.img">Battery</a>
        </td>
            <td align="left">3/16/2016
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="a" align="b">
        <span class="i"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" name="chkBox" value="101"/>
        </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/links/items/101.img">Polish</a>
    </td>
        <td align="left">3/16/2016
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="a" align="b">
        <span class="i"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxClass" name="chkBox" value="101" disabled/>
        </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/links/items/102.img">Polish</a>
    </td>
        <td align="left">3/16/2014
        </td>
</tr>
```

Objective is to get all the **href**'s only when sibling's check-box is disabled.I have little experience with XPath but I manage to get all the **href**'s using following expression but stuck on how to limit the selection to only disabled check-boxs.

```
var hrefs = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr/td[2]/a"));
```

I done quite a bit of trial and error with "preceding-sibling" but didn't get much further. For example I tried to hard-code href and see if I can get to the check-box element so later I can generalize it in a loop and check the "Selected" property of the checkbox. However following did not work.

```
var checkbox = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[a[@href='links/items/100.img']]/preceding-sibling::td[1]"));
```

My hunch is that the solution may be simple as one XPath expression for this so I can avoid loop, would be helpful to get feedback from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to filter elements by siblings, parents, etc, it's simpler to select the TR elements that suit your criteria, then get the A elements inside the matcheds TRs.

The TR elements that suit your criteria are those who have an embedded disabled input:

```
//tr[td[1]//input[@disabled]]
```

Then you want to get the A element inside each matched TR, therefore you append `/td[2]/a`.

The final XPath extpression to get the A elements is:

```
//tr[td[1]//input[@disabled]]/td[2]/a
```

From this you can use the same method to retrieve the href attributes as you originally did.

[Edited by OP] For future reference its worth mentioning that to get to the actual href attribute use selenium  IWebElement's GetAttribute() method with "href" as a parameter i-e GetAttribute("href") . For some reason selenium driver for IE( tested on version 9 in this case) is giving error when XPath expression "//tr[td[1]//input[@disabled]]/td[2]/a/@href" is used as mentioned in one of the responses. As the above method works fine and solves the original problem this solution is complete.

Comment: Thanks Tamas, your answer was really helpful. However, your final XPath expression on execution gave an error "The xpath expression '//tr[td[1]//input[@disabled]]/td[2]/a/@href]' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement". So I tweaked it a bit to "//tr[td[1]//input[@disabled]]/td[2]/a" and then get the "href" attribute using IWebElement's GetAttribute("href") method which gave me the actual URL. I don't mind marking your response as an answer but perhaps you may want to update your XPath before I do so.

Comment: I see, so /@href does not play well with `driver.FindElements`. Makes a lot of sense. Luckily I have already updated the XPath to an even shorter one. (See above)

Comment: I tried your updated XPath expression, now I am getting way too many matched elements in return, even the one's that don't have check-box disabled. I am curious though, when your take out @href from your orginal XPath then I believe your also forfeit the ability to get href directly as a return element, meaning your have to fetch it as an attribute using GetAttribute method as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I modified back the XPath that worked for you... please note that the previous one was also worked for me using Google Chrome. I don't have your exact (C#, some HTML parser / XPath engine of Selenium) environment to make sure it works for you, but I think you have already got the idea. Feel free to edit my answer if you think it can be more complete.

Comment: I update your original answer and also marked it as such. Thanks for your help.